# How to split the result of PTBTokenizer into sentences?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I know I could use `DocumentPreprocessor` to split a text into sentence. But it does not provide enough information if one wants to convert the tokenized text back to the original text. So I have to use `PTBTokenizer`, which has an `invertible` option.

However, `PTBTokenizer` simply returns an iterator of all the tokens (`CoreLabel`s) in a document. It does not split the document into sentences.

[The documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) says:

> The output of PTBTokenizer can be post-processed to divide a text into sentences.

But this is obviously not trivial.

Is there a class in the Stanford NLP library that can take as input a sequence of `CoreLabel`s, and output sentences? Here's what I mean exactly:

```
List<List<CoreLabel>> split(List<CoreLabel> documentTokens);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the StanfordCoreNLP class.  Here is some sample code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class PipelineExample {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        // build pipeline                                                                                                                                         
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = " I am a sentence.  I am another sentence.";
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        System.out.println(annotation.get(TextAnnotation.class));
        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            System.out.println(sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class));
            for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.println(token.after() != null);
                System.out.println(token.before() != null);
                System.out.println(token.beginPosition());
                System.out.println(token.endPosition());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Will `before()`, `after()`, `beginPosition()` and `endPosition()` be implemented (i.e., not merely returning `null`s) in the resulting `CoreMap`s?

Comment: Yes all of those are being set.